# Get Distinct results of all columns based on MAX DATE of one

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

Using SQL Server 2012

I have seen a few threads about this topic but I can't find one that involves multiple joins in the query. I can't create a VIEW on this database so the joins are needed.

The Query

```
SELECT 

      p.Price
      ,s.Type
      ,s.Symbol
      , MAX(d.Date) Maxed
  FROM AdventDW.dbo.FactPrices p
  INNER JOIN dbo.DimSecurityMaster s
  ON s.SecurityID = p.SecurityID
  INNER JOIN dbo.DimDateTime d
   ON
  p.DateTimeKey = d.DateTimeKey
  GROUP BY p.Price ,
           s.Type ,
           s.Symbol
ORDER BY s.Symbol
```

The query works but does not produce distinct results. I am using Order by to validate the results, but it is not required once I get it working. I  The result set looks like this.

```
Price   Type    Symbol  Maxed
10.57   bfus    *bbkd           3/31/1989
10.77   bfus    *bbkd           2/28/1990
100.74049   cbus    001397AA6       8/2/2005
100.8161    cbus    001397AA6       7/21/2005
```

The result set I want is

```
Price   Type    Symbol  Maxed
10.77   bfus    *bbkd           2/28/1990
100.74049   cbus    001397AA6       8/2/2005
```

Here were a few other StackOverflow threads I tried but couldn't get t work with my specific query

[How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

[SQL Selecting distinct rows from multiple columns based on max value in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951135/sql-selecting-distinct-rows-from-multiple-columns-based-on-max-value-in-one-colu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want data for the maximum date, use `row_number()` rather than `group by`:

```
SELECT ts.*
FROM (SELECT p.Price, s.Type, s.Symbol, d.Date,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.Type, s.Symbol
                                ORDER BY d.Date DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM AdventDW.dbo.FactPrices p INNER JOIN
           dbo.DimSecurityMaster s
           ON s.SecurityID = p.SecurityID INNER JOIN
           dbo.DimDateTime d
           ON p.DateTimeKey = d.DateTimeKey
     ) ts
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY s.Symbol;
```

Comment: This query achieves the desired result. Needed one small edit where I changed Order BY s.symbol to ts.symbol. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a derived table since you really only want to group the `DateTimeKey` table to get the `MAX` date.

```
SELECT p.Price ,
       s.Type ,
       s.Symbol ,
       tmp.MaxDate
FROM AdventDW.dbo.FactPrices p
INNER JOIN dbo.DimSecurityMaster s ON s.SecurityID = p.SecurityID
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT MAX(d.Date) AS MaxDate ,
           d.DateTimeKey
   FROM dbo.DimDateTime d
   GROUP BY d.DateTimeKey ) tmp ON p.DateTimeKey = tmp.DateTimeKey
ORDER BY s.Symbol;
```

Comment: How do you know there is a [Date] field in FactPrices (alias p), you JOIN with this new field also? The join is on DateTimeKey only.

Comment: Yep, my bad @Uporabnik003 not sure how/why I put that in there!

Answer (score 1):

```
    /* 
    this is your initial select which is fine because this is base from your original criteria, 
I cannot ignore this so i'll keep this in-tact. Instead from here i'll create a temp
    */

  SELECT 
      p.Price
      , s.Type
      , s.Symbol
      , MAX(d.Date) Maxed
  INTO #tmpT
  FROM AdventDW.dbo.FactPrices p
  INNER JOIN dbo.DimSecurityMaster s
      ON s.SecurityID = p.SecurityID
  INNER JOIN dbo.DimDateTime d
      ON p.DateTimeKey = d.DateTimeKey
  GROUP BY p.Price ,
       s.Type ,
       s.Symbol
  ORDER BY s.Symbol

SELECT innerTable.Price, innerTable.Symbol, innerTable.Type, innerTable.Maxed 
FROM (

   SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Symbol, t1.Type, t1.Maxed ORDER BY t1.Maxed DESC) as row 
      , *
   FROM #tmpT AS t1
) AS innerTable
WHERE row = 1

DROP TABLE #tmpT
```

Comment: Your query produces the following errors Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "t1.Symbol" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "t1.Type" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "t1.Maxed" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "t1.Maxed" could not be bound.

Comment: My apologies, please see edit, see FROM #tmpT AS t1, yeah I missed this.